# SDL Tridion 2013 upgrade IE 9, IE 10 & IE 11 Issues

Tags: 2013-sp1

We have recently upgraded to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. While testing the basic content manager features, found some issues w.r.t IE 9, IE 10 & IE 11 versions.

- While creating a schema, unable to select the Dropdown menu & unable to select the Design tab
- The icons on the Ribbon toolbar are not loading properly.

Supported browsers(as per live content): SDL supports Microsoft Internet Explorer 10.0 and the latest versions of Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

However, it works fine with Chrome & Firefox.

Please let me know if you know any work around for this issue.

Comment: Make sure you followed the configuration steps. The first issue you mention seems to be IE security settings (the dreaded Trusted Zone thing) and the 2nd one seems like a browser cache issue. IE 10 and IE 11 do work with Tridion 2013 SP1, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE tends to have issues most often due to the complexity of its configuration:

- Have you placed the Tridion CM webapplication in the Local Intranet zone and does this zone have it's standard security settings? Many companies employ policy files to adjust these settings which can wreak havoc with Tridion.
- Have you tried disabling helpers and extensions in IE? I remember google dictionary helpers breaking Tridion back in the day.

Comment: I'm trying with the options you have mentioned above. But I'm working on the client n/w through Citrix, I do not have privileges to change the settings & add our CME web application in the Local Intranet zone

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your browser is not rendering the site in compatibility mode.

Change the compatibility settings by going to Tools->Compatibility View Settings-> Unchecked the check boxes if any of them is checked.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the option in IE under Tools > Compatibility View Settings and then refresh the browser. This will resolve the issue.